# и() что оно означает() знаю

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> А вот я слышал это слово единожды и() что оно означает() знаю!

**Здесь нужны запятые? А если два тире поставить? Или же после "и" не ставить ничего, а после "означает" - тире?**

Comment: Я сделал, как Вы сказали, Александр! Зачем мне делать себе хуже?

Comment: Спасибо........